# Function hangs UI

Tags: android, api, flutter

> I am working with Dart, AndroidStudio, Flutter

I need to call a function to hash my Password. The hash function takes time to execute. The code should run on press. Function is:

`String getHash(Stirng input)`

I call it a follows:

```
onPressed:{
           newPass=getHash(currentPass);
          }
```

It blocks the UI thread. The function is from some API hence it cannot be edited.

I made an `async` method and called `getHash()` in the `async` funtion.

```
Future<String> asyncMethodToGetHash(String input) async{
     return await geHash(input);
}
```

But still it blocks the UI thread. How should I call it so that UI is not blocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `compute()` method provided by the flutter that will run the code in a separate isolate(dart equivalent to threads). Something like this:

```dart
static String getHash(String input){
     return hash(input); // your code to calculate hash here.
}

String computeHash(String input){
     return await compute(getHash, input);
}
```

Remember that the function you pass to the `compute()` method has to be static, and can accept only one parameter. As isolates don't share memory so every variable to be used in the function has to be passed as a parameter. So if you have to pass multiple methods to the function, you will have to make a list of parameters.